# Regular Expression multiple times for entire document

Tags: regex

I have a table of contents in which i want to remove all (...)'s   so have the regular expression `(\.\.+)` which matches only the first set of the periods.  How do I make this be true for every set of periods in the string?

http://regex101.com/r/hO8jX9

Comment: One or more `\.+`, two or more `\.{2,}` (or `\.\.+` what you have), three or more `\.{3,}`. Then just match in global context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`g` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) if the regex needs to be tested against all possible matches in a string. 
As shown [Here.](http://regex101.com/r/cL6qV3)